Extracting file paths, occasionally returns special characters (~$) in file names
When extracting file paths, not all but a few results are returned that contain special characters ~$ at the start of the file name. I am looking to compare these file paths with another list, thus the special characters prevent the ability to find a proper match.
The current code:
import os

for path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(root): 
    for name in files:
        # For each file we find, we need to ensure it is a .docx file before adding
        #  it to our list
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(path, name))[1] == ".docx":
            document_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))

The majority of results are satisfactory, for example:
X:/Serial Numbers/6200\Test Company\6275 Documents\6275rA_Order_TEST_120221.docx

however there are occasional results of special characters that do not exist in file name:
X:/Serial Numbers/6200\Test Company\6275 Documents\~$75rA_Order_MERZ_120221.docx

Preferably seeking a solution that does not rely on a string replace method.

As has been pointed out in another answer, files beginning with "~$" are probably Microsoft temporary files.
The pathlib module (preferred over os nowadays) offers are more OO approach to interacting with your filesystem.
In this case I would suggest using a generator in preference to the current structure.
Something like this:
from pathlib import Path
from collections.abc import Iterable

def genpaths(directory: Path) -> Iterable[Path]:
    ignore = ("~$", ) # add any additional filename prefixes to be ignored here
    for fullpath in directory.rglob("*.docx"):
        if not fullpath.name.startswith(ignore):
            yield fullpath

root = Path("the_root_directory")

for c in genpaths(root):
    print(c) # the files of interest


This is helpful, thanks so much.

These are temporary files created by Microsoft Office whilst you are modifying the file. Usually it should clean up after itself; but now, this is Microsoft we are talking about.
The obvious solution is to skip files whose name begins with these two characters:
for path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(root): 
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith(("~$", ".")):
            continue
        ... # the rest of your code

I also added "." to the patterns to ignore, mainly just to demonstrate that you can pass multiple patterns to .startswith if you need to. (Dot files are hidden files on Unix, but not really seen on Windows.)
It's not clear why you thought a "string replace method" would be necessary or helpful here. Perhaps you meant to suggest that you don't want to hardcode the pattern? In that case, you could use a regular expression, perhaps.
import re

...
        if re.match(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]', name):
            continue

This looks for a name whose first character is not A through Z, or a through z, or 0 through 9. (Obviously, if you have files with names in Hebrew, Russian, Hindi, Chinese, etc, or even French, Spanish, or German, you need a more elaborate expression.)
